# OS X shell scripting: How to pause execution till after Finder restarts?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, finder

This is about shell scripting on Mac OS X. I want to write a bash script that relaunches the Finder and does something afterwards. How can I add a delay after the `killall` command so that the next command only executes once Finder has relaunched?

```
killall Finder
# wait till Finder is relaunched
# Do something else...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test for the presence or absence of the Finder in the list of processes with `ps ax|grep Finder$` but it could be that the Finder, ***while rebooting***, is already listed as a process...

Comment: I just tried this. It works fine the first time (the Finder process appears as `(Finder)` and this can be identified) but all successive attempts failed, as Finder rebooted too quickly for `ps` to get the process list before Finder could reappear.